# can't make a post request with GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, guzzle

i'm trying to make a post requet with GuzzleHttp from one application to another like this :

```
public function connect() {
    $request = $this->client;
    $options = [
        'json' => [
            "email" => self::authEmail,
            "password"=> self::authKey
        ]
    ];
    $response = $request->request('POST',self::apiURL,$options);
    return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['token'];
}

public function sendMail($body) {
    $request = $this->client;
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $this->connect(),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ];


    $response = $request->request('POST','http://localhost:8000/api/email/process-booking',[
        'headers' => $headers,
        'json' => [
            'name' => 'Example name',
        ],

        'debug'=> true,

    ]);

    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException: Server error: `POST http://localhost:8000/api/email/process-booking` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:

when i enable the debug i get this error:

> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 56
>
> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 56
>
> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 56
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:186 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(517): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(146): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::retryFailedRewind(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\ in C:\xampp\htdocs\comunReservacion\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186

the weird is that the connection goes successfully, the problem appears only when i try to post data

Comment: Is the output of http://localhost:8000/api/email/process-booking valid JSON?

Comment: no it gives error 500 in symfony console, to simplify it  i return a json response with a string text